# Devise Redirect After Signup: What is super

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise, model

I want to redirect to a page after signup.

Here is my registrations_controller.rb for devise:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  include ApplicationHelper
  layout "signup_layout", only: [:create, :new]
  def create
    super
    redirect_to("create_company") #Can't use this
  end

  def new
    super
  end

  def edit
    super
  end
end
```

Only problem is that I can't use `redirect_to("create_company")` because:

> Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.
>   Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most
>   once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate
>   execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after
>   redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and
>   return".

I would like to know what super is. Because it seems super is what is trying to redirecting `redirect_to("create_company")`.

**My question is** how can I redirect to a page after signup & retreive the user_id of the newly created account on the following page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super` is used to call the parent class method when you are overriding it in a subclass:

```
class Parent
  def self.foo *args, **kwargs
    puts args.inspect if args.any?
    puts kwargs.inspect if kwargs.any?
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def self.foo *args, **kwargs
    super
  end
end

irb(main):052:0> Child.foo(1, 2, 'foo', bar: 'baz')
[1, 2, "foo"]
{:bar=>"baz"}
=> nil
```

When you call `super` with no arguments it simply forwards all the received arguments & block to the superclass method.

In Devise you simply need to override the `after_sign_up_path_for` method.

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(user)
  new_company_path
end
```

---

Another issue is that `redirect_to("create_company")` will not work. At least not in the way you think. `redirect_to` takes a string, a hash or a model and is often pretty smart at figuring out what to do.

However when you pass a string it either needs to be a path or a full URI. Passing the name of *named route* as a string will not work. Instead if you have a named route you need to use the route helper, for example:

```
redirect_to new_company_path
```

If you use rails build in `resource` and `resource` macros (if you are not you should be) to create routes it will create such helpers for you.

Run `rake routes` to see a list of routes and the names.

---

This is what your complete controller would look like. There is no need to have the `create`, `new` and `edit` actions as you are not actually doing any overrides.

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  layout "signup_layout", only: [:create, :new]

  private
  def after_sign_up_path_for(user)
    new_company_path
  end
end
```

Comment: This is what I have in my controller: http://pastebin.com/aFgbEHQn However I still get the same error.

Comment: My bad, your `after_sign_up_path_for` method is supposed to return the path - not redirect. The actual redirect is done inside the create action.

Comment: this is the first time I am using rails. How would I redirect inside the create action?

Comment: The thing here is that you don't. Devise will take care of that, what you do simply change the url that Devise redirects to by overriding its `after_sign_up_path_for` method. See my edit.

Comment: How do I set up the variable new_company_path for it to redirect to the "/create_company" page?

Comment: You don't. In rails conventions the page would be `/companies/new`. You set the route up by adding `resources :companies` in your `resources/routes.rb`. That will among other things create the `new_company_path` helper method.

Answer (score 1):

From ruby-doc.org:

> Called with no arguments and no empty argument list, super calls the
>   appropriate method with the same arguments, and the same code block,
>   as those used to call the current method. Called with an argument list
>   or arguments, it calls the appropriate methods with exactly the
>   specified arguments (including none, in the case of an empty argument
>   list indicated by empty parentheses).

What `super` is doing in your code sample is calling the `create` method of the default Devise RegistrationsController, which already contains a redirect. When you add your own redirect at the end, you're creating the multiple redirect condition.

You don't seem to want do do anything different by overriding the default `create` method, so what you should really be doing is creating an [`after_sign_up_path_for`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration)) method to let Devise know where to redirect after a user signs up successfully.

Remove your overridden `create` method and add this to your registrations_controller.rb

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(user)
  user_path(user)
  # you can get the user ID from the passed in user object (user.id)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through a situation similar to yours. I needed to make a specific redirect if the user came from the cell phone.
I will leave it here to complement the previous answer:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(professional)
  Browser.new("Some User Agent")
  if browser.device.iphone? || browser.platform.android?
    access_not_allowed_path
  else
    super
  end
end
```