# double rendering after super is called in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, devise, super

```
class CustomSessionsController < DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController

  def create
    binding.pry
    super
    confirmed = true

    binding.pry
    if current_user.present? && confirmed
      render json: { message: "removed" }, status: :ok ("won't render")
    else
      redirect_to new_user_session_url ("won't render")
    end
  end

  def destroy
    super
  end

  private
  
  def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
    redirect_to new_user_session_url
  end

end
```

Is it possible to stop the super from rendering so the other renders would work?

I have tried after_sign_in_path_for just like devise recommends, but I still keep getting double render error.

similar to this post.

[Devise Redirect After Signup: What is super](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31838897/devise-redirect-after-signup-what-is-super)

Comment: https://devise-token-auth.gitbook.io/devise-token-auth/usage/overrides#overriding-rendering-methods

Answer (score 0):

try setting up flash.now(:notice) = 'x' or flash[:warning] = 'y' to get the flash[:notice] on the normal render results.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the code from `Devise::SessionsController` to this file and then remove the render methods from it. Then you could replace that with your render methods based on your flow.

What you'll be doing is copy the code for the super here and make changes to it. Instead to super being called, the substituted code will be executed.